# Replacing the elements along 2 dimensions of a matrix by values of a different matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to replace the elements along 2 dimensions of a matrix by the elements of another matrix.

Let me share the code so that you can understand it better:

```
import numpy as np

zeros = np.zeros([1,4,4,1])
#zeros.shape gives (1,4,4,1)

my_matrix = np.random.rand(4,4)
#my_matrix.shape gives (4,4)

for i in range(zeros.shape[0]):
  for j in range(zeros.shape[3]):
    zeros[i,:,:,j] = my_matrix

print(zeros)
>>>
array([[[[0.42637021],
         [0.99836782],
         [0.74446878],
         [0.73064106]],

        [[0.20887195],
         [0.2531161 ],
         [0.4798265 ],
         [0.8722573 ]],

        [[0.23242607],
         [0.31000575],
         [0.98238762],
         [0.43288297]],

        [[0.84283148],
         [0.66117088],
         [0.41227247],
         [0.93539199]]]])
```

Now, the code  works just fine. However, I was thinking if there is a better way, using matrices and avoiding loops to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 zeros[...] = matrix[None,...,None]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the original shape of `zeros` try:

```
zeros[0, :, :, 0] = my_matrix
```